# Proving f is continuous

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Question states:

Show that $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is continuous at $a \in \Bbb R^n$ if for any continuous path $\gamma: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^n$ with $\gamma(0)=a$ we have $$\lim_{t \to 0} \hspace{3pt}f(\gamma(t)) = f(a).$$

I was told that I HAVE TO prove this by contrapositive, meaning that if $f$ is not continuous, then we can construct a continuous function $\gamma$ such that $\gamma(0) = a$ but
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \hspace{3pt}f(\gamma(t)) \neq f(a).$$

Comment: You are missing a limit on the left hand side.

Answer (score 1):

For the given question, you can prove it directly from the properties of $\gamma(t)$ at 0 using epsilon-delta arguments.

1. For any $\delta >0$, we can find a $\mu >0$ such that if $|t-0| < \mu$ then

$$ |\gamma(t)-a| < \delta$$

This follows from the continuity of $\gamma$.

2. Since 
   $$\lim_{t \to 0} \hspace{3pt}f(\gamma(t)) = f(a)$$

we know that for any $\epsilon>0$, we can find a $\mu>0$ such that if $|t-0|<\mu$ then

$$ |f(\gamma(t)) - f(a)| < \epsilon$$

Putting 1 and 2 together you get the proof. For any $\epsilon$, find a small enough $\mu$, and this will also give you a bound on the $\delta$. Any delta smaller than this bound would serve your purpose.

As for the contrapositive, I think the correct statement would be a continuous $\gamma(t)$ s.t. $ \gamma(0) = a$ and
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \hspace{3pt} f(\gamma(t)) \neq f(a)$$

gives you the result that $f$ is not continuous.